# Vertical and horizontal lines that always intersect mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, css, mouse-cursor

I am trying to create two lines ( 1 vertical of 100 VH and 1 px width and one horizontal of 100vw and 1 px height ) that always follow mouse cursor and interest each other. I have two problems with my code: 1) I don't know what value of height I have to assign on the vertical line ( with the horizontal it was easy, I set it at 200 vw and body overflow-x hidden so it's ok ) and 2) when I scroll down, until I don't move my mouse, the horizontal line remains on the same position, it follows the cursor only after I change the mouse position. Here is my code:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX) + "px;")
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 5000px;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
}

.cursor-lines {
  position: relative;
}

.vt {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200vh;
  top: -100vh;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
}

.hl {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
  height: 1px;
  width: 200vw;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="cursor-lines">
    <div class="vt"></div>
    <div class="hl"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.cursor` should be a fixed area, and you should use `clientX` and `clientY`, since they are relative to the client area, and not the entire page.

Instead of moving the entire cursor, which requires an overflow, move the `.vt` line horizontally, and the `.hl` line vertically.

```js
const cursorVT = document.querySelector('.vt')
const cursorHL = document.querySelector('.hl')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursorVT.setAttribute('style', `left: ${e.clientX}px;`)
  cursorHL.setAttribute('style', `top: ${e.clientY}px;`)
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.vt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background: black;
}

.hl {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <div class="vt"></div>
  <div class="hl"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! I didn't think about that! Cool~